# Probability of getting at least four ones in a row when a six-sided die is rolled seven times

Tags: probability

> Let's say you roll a dice that consist of 1 to 6, 7 times. (e.g: 1, 1, 3, 4, 6, 2, 2)  What are the chances that you would get 1 four times in a row?

I tried to approach this with

$$(1/6)^4 \cdot (5/6)^3 + (1/6)^5 \cdot (5/6)^2 + (1/6)^6 \cdot (1/6)^1 + (1/6)^7 \cdot (1/6)^0$$

However, I am not really certain if my equations are correct.

Comment: This is not correct.  You only counted possibilities who explicitly **started** with at least four $1$'s.  You missed possibilities like $4111123$

Comment: For a corrected approach, I recommend breaking into cases based on the starting position of the run of $1$'s, noting that the number immediately preceding the run (*if any*) must not be a $1$, and numbers prior to that as well as numbers following the run of $1$'s can be *anything* (*including more 1's*).  Fortunately, here, you don't have to worry about multiple separate long runs of $1$'s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that there are six possible outcomes for each of the seven rolls, so there are $6^7$ outcomes in the sample space.  In what follows, I will assume that the die is fair, in which case each of the $6^7$ outcomes is equally likely to occur.

**Method 1:**  We use the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Notice that any run of at least four consecutive ones must begin in one of the first four positions.  Let $A_i$, $1 \le i \le 4$, denote an outcome in which there is a run of four consecutive ones beginning in the $i$th position.  Then we wish to find $|A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup A_4|$.  By the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle,
\begin{align*}
|A_1 & \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup A_4|\\
& = |A_1| + |A_2| + |A_3| + |A_4|\\
& \qquad - |A_1 \cap A_2| - |A_1 \cap A_3| - |A_1 \cap A_4| - |A_2 \cap A_3| - |A_2 \cap A_4| - |A_3 \cap A_4|\\
& \quad\qquad + |A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3| + |A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_4| + |A_1 \cap A_3 \cap A_4| + |A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4|\\
& \qquad\qquad - |A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4|
\end{align*}

$|A_1|$:  There is only one way to have a one in each of the first positions.  There are six possible outcomes for each of the last three positions, so $|A_1| = 6^3$.

By symmetry, $|A_1| = |A_2| = |A_3| = |A_4|$.

$|A_1 \cap A_2|$:  Since the first four positions and the second four positions overlap, if there is a one in the first four positions and a one in the second four positions, then there must be a one in the first five positions.  There are six possible outcomes in each of the last two positions, so $|A_1 \cap A_2| = 6^2$.

By symmetry, $|A_1 \cap A_2| = |A_2 \cap A_3| = |A_3 \cap A_4|$.

$|A_1 \cap A_3|$:  Since the first four positions and the third four positions overlap, if there is a one in the first four positions and a one in the third four positions, then there must be a one in the first six positions.  There are six possible outcomes for the last position, so $|A_1 \cap A_3| = 6$.

By symmetry, $|A_1 \cap A_3| = |A_2 \cap A_4|$.

$|A_1 \cap A_4|$:  Since the first four positions and the last four positions overlap, if there is a one in the first four positions and a one in the last four positions, then there must be a one in all seven positions, so $|A_1 \cap  A_4| = 1$.

$|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3|$:  Since the first four, second four, and third four positions overlap, if there is a one in the first four positions, second four positions, and third four positions, then there must be a one in the first six positions.  There are six possible outcomes for the last position, so $|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3| = 6$.

By symmetry, $|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3| = |A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4|$.

$|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_4|$:  Since the first four, second four, and last four positions overlap, if there is a one in the first four positions, second four positions, and last four positions, then there must be a one in all seven positions, so $|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_4| = 1$.

By symmetry, $|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_4| = |A_1 \cap A_3 \cap A_4|$.

$|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4|$:  This can only occur if there is a one in all seven positions, so $|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4| = 1$.

By the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, the number of favorable outcomes is
$$4 \cdot 6^3 - 3 \cdot 6^2 - 2 \cdot 6 - 1 + 2 \cdot 6 + 2 \cdot 1 - 1 = 4 \cdot 6^3 - 3 \cdot 6^2$$
Hence, the probability of a run of at least four consecutive ones is
$$\frac{4 \cdot 6^3 - 3 \cdot 6^2}{6^7}$$

**Method 2:**  We use the method outlined by JMorawitz in the comments to count the favorable cases.  Since there are only seven rolls, it is not possible to have two disjoint runs of at least four consecutive ones.

*The run of at least four consecutive ones begins in the first position*:  The first four positions must be filled with ones.  There are six possible outcomes for each of the last three positions, so there are $6^3$ such outcomes.

*The run of at least four consecutive ones is in the second position*:  The first position must be filled with a number other than one, which can occur in five ways.  The next four positions must be filled with ones.  The last two positions can each be filled in six ways, so there are $5 \cdot 6^2$ such outcomes.

*The run of at least four consecutive ones begins in the third position*:  There are six ways to fill the first position, five ways to fill the second position since it cannot be a one, one way to fill the next four positions with ones, and six ways to fill the last position, so there are $5 \cdot 6^2$ such outcomes.

*The run of four consecutive ones begins in the fourth position*:  There are six ways to fill each of the first two positions, five ways to fill the third position since it cannot be a one, and one way to fill the last four positions with ones, so there are $5 \cdot 6^2$ such outcomes.

Since the above cases are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, the number of favorable outcomes is
$$6^3 + 5 \cdot 6^2 + 5 \cdot 6^2 + 5 \cdot 6^2 = 6^3 + 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 6^2$$
Hence, the desired probability is
$$\frac{6^3 + 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 6^2}{6^7}$$

**Note:** Both of the above methods would be hard to generalize to $n$ rolls since if $n \ge 8$, there could be two or more disjoint runs of four consecutive ones.  To handle that issue, it would be easier to find a recurrence relation for the number of outcomes in which no runs of at least four consecutive ones appear and subtract that amount from the total to find the number of favorable outcomes.

Answer (score 1):

Amount of possible situations: `6^(7) ▸ 279936`

How many different times can you get four ones:
1111xxx, x1111xx, xx1111x, xxx1111
Where x is any other number than 1 (from 2 to 6).

We have 4 situations where there is 3 x's which can be any other number than 1. To calculate this we raise the number of other number to the power of different possibilities and multiply that with the number of different situations. Thus giving us `4*5^3 ▸ 3000`
So you have 500 different possibilities where you have exactly 4 ones.
Every number has the same number of these: `500*6 ▸ 3000`
That's how many different situation you have where there's exactly four same numbers.

Let's calculate how many has 5 ones
11111xx, x1111x, xx11111
`3*5^(2) ▸ 75`
75 numbers have exactly five ones
The other 5 number of the dice (instead of 1): `75*6 ▸ 450`
That's how many has exactly 5 of the same number

Same thing with 6 ones:
x111111, 111111x
`2*5^(1) ▸ 10`
If included the other 5 number of the dice: `10*6 ▸ 60`

Same with 7 ones:
1111111
We know that we have six different numbers in use, so this is six.

Let's add these togeter `3000+450+60+6 ▸ 3516`
So the probability of getting any six numbers in a row is `((3516)/(279936)`
which is approximately 1.26%

But if you want to have exactly four numbers it would be 3000/279936, which is approximately 1.07%

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to calculate it. Sorry for my english :)

***correction***:

1111xxx should not be calculated as 5^3 but as $5\cdot6^2$

xxx1111 arrangement is about the same so $2\cdot5\cdot6^2$

x1111xx and xx1111x, you can only have one six, so $2\cdot6\cdot5^2$
so the total is: $2\cdot5\cdot6^2+2\cdot6\cdot5^2=660$

Same with 5 ones
xx1111 and 1111xx = $2\cdot6\cdot5=60$
x11111x = $5\cdot5=25$

Six and seven have been calculated correctly
the total is:
660+60+25+10+1=731

(I've now noticed that i've calculated the probability of any six numbers happening, when the question asks about four ones in a row)

So the probability is $\frac{756}{279936}$, which is approximately 0.27 %

Comment: Where did you count arrangements such as $1111511$?

Comment: I would like to ask you if this is correct. Thanks :)

Comment: $660+60+25+10+1=756$, not $731$. Also, what do you mean by "But this works with every number on the dice so it must be multiplied with 6"?

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to put the 25 to the calculator. And the latter part meant that you can have like 2222xx, but then I noticed the question asks for four ones, not four of any number.

Comment: Your revised strategy is sound.  However, your answer is not clearly written.  For clarity, please eliminate the parts of your answer that do not use your revised strategy.  Also, the wording could be improved.  When you have a run of exactly $k$ ones, $4 \leq k \leq 7$, you are choosing how to fill the other $7 - k$ positions.  In your count, there are $5$ choices for the positions immediately preceding or immediately following the run of ones and $6$ choices for the positions not adjacent to the run of ones.  However, you did not actually say that.

Comment: I should add that your answer is correct.